# Fix redraw delay in table-mode

Tags: table

How can I eliminate the 200ms delay before text is redrawn in table-mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default settings in table-mode have a built-in delay which makes your text invisible for 200ms. Assuming your computer is fast enough to handle it, you can eliminate this with the following settings:

```
;; 16ms = 60fps
(setq table-time-before-update 0.016)
(setq table-time-before-reformat 0.016)
```